# Best way to save source functions

Tags: c++, ide, save

Newbie question: I've been trying to complete a couple of problems from the [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) site, using Visual studios 2010 as my IDE.

What is the best way for me to save and store the source so that I don't have to have 500 projects created?

Comment: You can make your own header file with every function[s] you use for each problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function for each problem, then just change which function you call from main.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to "save" source code is in a version control system. My preference is [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

I haven't used Visual Studio 2010 in anger, but I'm sure you can have multiple source files in a single project. You don't need to create one project per problem (although it may be a neat